# How do I add multiple images in a single row under a single caption?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to do something like this:

[https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/figures.en.html#Illustrati][1]

but with multiple images sitting on a single row with the caption right above it.

Comment: Please include a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example in your question: we unfortunately cannot write code out of thin air for you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```html
<div class="row">
    <figure>
        <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many images as you want under a single caption, but you will have to take care of heights of all images.

```css
figure {
  display: table;
  outline: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: top;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <p><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg" height="100px" />
    <img src="https://c.wallhere.com/photos/71/12/tiger_animals-50159.jpg!d" height="100px" />
    <img src="https://c.pxhere.com/photos/62/7d/animal_animal_photography_blur_close_up_endangered_forest_furry_glare-1175431.jpg!d" height="100px" />
    <figcaption>Saint Tropez and its fort in the evening sun</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

img tags by default are inline.  You just need to make sure the default widths aren't to large.  You can scale the pictures by specifying their height.

```html
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/18/17/42/image-1465348_1280.jpg" height="100px"/>
    <img src="https://c.wallhere.com/photos/71/12/tiger_animals-50159.jpg!d" height="100px" />
    <img src="https://c.pxhere.com/photos/62/7d/animal_animal_photography_blur_close_up_endangered_forest_furry_glare-1175431.jpg!d" height="100px" />
```